# iOS Xcode development on MacBook Air 2015

Tags: macbook-pro, ios, xcode, development, apple-inc

I am deciding to get a 2015 MacBook Air for iOS development, and was wondering how well my specs on the custom macbook I am ordering. I am getting the 13 inch 2015 MacBook Air 8 GB RAM 1.6 gigahertz fifth generation Intel processors. Would these specs run well with Xcode 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MacBook airs are computers generally aimed at people travelling a lot but have lots of intense work to do with production etc. If you have a different MacBook that has more power I would say it's a good choice. Overall, the xCode 6 would run on it.

However, for the price the new MacBook comes and the specs it has, I would suggest gathering a little bit more money and investing it in the MacBook Pro 13". It comes with a 2.7GHz i5 processor, 8GB or RAM and a better graphics card.